# Get the height of "notch" so contents won't be cut off

Tags: android, android-windowmanager, windowinsets, android-cutout

How can I get the height of recent android phones' notch, preferably in pixels?

I have an implementation where an image MUST be at the top in full screen.

With the addition of a notch to recently released phones, this image will be cut out by the notch. My idea is to get the notch height and add a margin above it dynamically to accommodate different notch sizes.

Any help or other approaches would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It should be the same as the status bar height.

Comment: Native API for [display cutout](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0#cutout) was only  added in android Pie so it's not really useful right now.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to get the cutout's height in pixels is to override `onAttachedToWindow()` function of your View. View being attached to window is the main requirement to `rootWindowInsets` being non-null. Note that it's safe to check SDK version, because complete support of cutout has been started since Android Pie.

```
override fun onAttachedToWindow() {
     super.onAttachedToWindow()
     layoutParams = LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT).apply {
           topMargin = 
               if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) rootWindowInsets?.displayCutout?.safeInsetTop ?: 0 
               else 0 
     }

}
```

In case that your View isn't CustomView you should add `OnAttachStateChangeListener`:

```
imageView.addOnAttachStateChangeListener(object : View.OnAttachStateChangeListener {
     override fun onViewDetachedFromWindow(v: View?) { }

     override fun onViewAttachedToWindow(v: View?) {
         // call the code from above starting from 'layoutParams = ...' on your View object
     }
})
```

Don't forget to change `LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT)` for your own needs.

Answer (score 1):

I used the method below(in Kotlin):

*It will only work in Android P and above.

*My activity is a full screen activity.

*My assumption is android phone with notches are relatively new will either come out of the box with Android P or have been rapidly updated to Android P.

Create a OnGlobalLayoutListener

```
private val onDisplayCutoutReadyListener : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener = ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener{
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {

        var displayCutout = window.decorView.rootWindowInsets.displayCutout
        if (displayCutout.boundingRects.size>0) {
            val notchRect = displayCutout.boundingRects.get(0)
            Log.v(TAG,"notch height in pixels="+notchRect.height())
        }
    }

}
```

Add the listener to your activity's rootview using .viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener()

```
layout_fullscreen.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(onDisplayCutoutReadyListener)
```

My layout xml where layout_fullscreen is the rootview.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout_fullscreen"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="0dp">
    <com.baidu.mapapi.map.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map_location"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Android Q (API level 29), you'd use the `windowInsets` to get the cutout/notch height using the below activity extension function:

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
fun Activity.getNotchHeight(): Int? =
    if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R)
        windowManager.currentWindowMetrics.windowInsets
            .displayCutout?.safeInsetTop
    else
        windowManager.defaultDisplay.cutout?.safeInsetTop
```